# Uncaught ReferenceError: rand_linea is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Alguién me podria decir porque me sale el error "Uncaught ReferenceError: rand_linea is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick" me e fijado en todo y no encuentro el porque, gracias por leer!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <script>
function test() {
    alert();
    var arrayData = new Array();
    var archivoTxt = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fileRuta = 'archivo.txt'
    archivoTxt.open("POST",fileRuta,false);
    archivoTxt.send(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++ {
        arrayData.push(txt[i]);
    }
    arrayData.forEach(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    var txt = archivoTxt.responseText;
    var rand_archivo = (fileRuta);
    var rand_contenido = (rand_archivo);
    var rand_linea = (rand_contenido);
}
    </script>
<form><input type="button" value="clickaqui" onclick="alert(rand_linea)">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Con definir la variable **fuera** de la función `test()` sería suficiente. El principal problema es que no podemos reproducir tu problema porque tiene muchos errores como la asignación `var txt = archivoTxt.responseText` **después** de intentar usar los datos en el bucle `for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++ {`, al que le falta un paréntesis (debería ser `for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {`). Y lo más importante: no sabemos qué quieres hacer con tu código, por lo que no sabemos si sería válido una simple inicialización o el botón no debería mostrarse hasta contener la información, etc.

Answer (score 0):

El error te salta porque cuando el navegador lee el archivo html intenta identificar el código y se encentra con que la variable `rand_linea` en ese momento no tiene ningún valor.

Para poder usar la variable `rand_linea` como una variable global, tienes que declararla fuera de la función. Además no es posible añadir una variable `JavaScript` al códgio `html` por lo que tendras que llamar a una función desde el método `onclick`.

El código se debería ver algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <script>

      var rand_linea = "";

      function test() {
          alert();
          var arrayData = new Array();
          var archivoTxt = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var fileRuta = 'archivo.txt'
          archivoTxt.open("POST",fileRuta,false);
          archivoTxt.send(null);
          for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++ {
              arrayData.push(txt[i]);
          }
          arrayData.forEach(function(data){
              console.log(data);
          });
          var txt = archivoTxt.responseText;
          var rand_archivo = (fileRuta);
          var rand_contenido = (rand_archivo);
          rand_linea = (rand_contenido);
      }

      function notificacion(){
         alert(rand_contenido);
      }
    </script>
<form><input type="button" value="clickaqui" onclick="notificacion()">
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: No me sirvio lo antes mencionado, me sigue dando el mismo error :/s

Comment: A ver si ahora te soluciona el problema

Answer (score 0):

La variable no esta definida cuando la usas, además en ningún momento llamas a la función test. Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <script>
      var rand_linea = "";
      function notificacion(){
         var arrayData = new Array();
          var archivoTxt = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var fileRuta = 'archivo.txt'
          archivoTxt.open("POST",fileRuta,false);
          archivoTxt.send(null);
          for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
              arrayData.push(txt[i]);
          }
          arrayData.forEach(function(data){
              console.log(data);
          });
          var txt = archivoTxt.responseText;
          var rand_archivo = (fileRuta);
          var rand_contenido = (rand_archivo);
          rand_linea = (rand_contenido);
         alert(rand_contenido);
      }
    </script>
<form><input type="button" value="clickaqui" onclick="notificacion()">
</form>
</body>
```

Si no quieres que se ejecute todo el codigo cada vez que le das a click tambien podrias añadir la lectura del archivo en el metodo onload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body>
        <script>
var rand_linea = "";
window.onload = function() {
  var arrayData = new Array();
              var archivoTxt = new XMLHttpRequest();
              var fileRuta = 'archivo.txt'
              archivoTxt.open("POST",fileRuta,false);
              archivoTxt.send(null);
              for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
                  arrayData.push(txt[i]);
              }
              arrayData.forEach(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              });
              var txt = archivoTxt.responseText;
              var rand_archivo = (fileRuta);
              var rand_contenido = (rand_archivo);
              rand_linea = (rand_contenido);
};

          
          function notificacion(){
             
             alert(rand_contenido);
          }
        </script>
    <form><input type="button" value="clickaqui" onclick="notificacion()">
    </form>
    </body>
```